# Language switcher, how to echo with variable instead with key for _lang line

Tags: php, codeigniter

I like to store my language lines in variables or array.

And I have this problem. How can I echo `$data["menu_production"]` 
instead of `$this->lang->line("menu_production");`? It works when I echo `($this->lang->line("menu_production");)` but not with `$data` or other variable. In my controller I call this function:

```
function index() {
  $data["menu_production"] = $this->lang->line("menu_production");
  $this->load->view('menu', $data);
}
```

Comment: It’s any object and line is even a method. You can implement ArrayAccess interface. http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround for this will be using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Let your language file has a key something like

```
$lang['custom_message'] = "Hello %s!";
```

Then use the language class as

```
echo sprintf($this->lang->line('custom_message'), 'world');
// output: Hello world!

$name = "John Doe";
echo sprintf($this->lang->line('custom_message'), $name);
// output: Hello John Doe!
```